# Make Spring ConstraintValidator throw Exception or return other code than 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I'm currently working on a simple validator that would check whether the annotated input value sent by my REST API consumer ​(let's call it a `code`) is registered or not within my database, and return BAD REQUEST when it is not. To do it, I'm asking an external service for list of registered codes. However, I'm working with microservices and I need to handle a situation when the external service doesn't respond correctly, e.g. `externalServiceClient.getCodes()` returns 503. This is my validator's code:

```
import com.company.myservice.externalService.ExternalServiceClient;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CodeAnnotationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CodeAnnotation, String> {

   ​private final ExternalServiceClient externalServiceClient;

   ​@Override
   ​public boolean isValid(String code, ConstraintValidatorContext context ){
       ​if(code == null) {
           ​return false;
       ​}

       ​String codeUpperCase = code.toUpperCase();

       ​if (!codeUpperCase.matches("^[A-Z][A-Z]\\d$")) {
           ​return false;
       ​}

       ​List<String> expectedCodes = externalServiceClient.getCodes();
       ​return expectedCodes.contains(codeUpperCase);
   ​}

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I get any kind of exception when trying to contact the external service, be it 503 or 404, I want to return INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. However, the `isValid` method returns 400 instead, which incorrectly blames my API consumer:

```
c.e.c.e.advice.CommonControllerAdvice    : Validation exception: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
```

I've tried catching the exception but it doesn't work since `isValid` is an overriden method and I can't just add `throws` on it.

Is there any possibility to overcome this and return error code 500 instead of 400?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a simpler way, but you could:

- Catch any exception coming from `externalServiceClient.getCodes()` and manually set a ConstraintViolation (see the methods on `ConstraintValidatorContext`).
- Use a `@ControllerAdvice` that catches the `ConstraintViolationException` and examines the message, and return an appropriate status code.

But this seems quite convoluted and maybe indicates that what you want to do is not really the job of a Validator, so maybe this check should be done not during the validation phase but during the normal service call phase.